# Little-group and spinor helicity

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, poincare-symmetry

I'm struggling a bit to understand the little group in the context of massless momenta and the spinor-helicity formalism.

I'll clarify notation and my understanding through a brief recap, and put the questions at the end.

We can express a momentum vector $p^\mu$ as a matrix through
$$
p^{\alpha \dot{\beta}}
=
p^\mu \sigma_\mu^{\alpha \dot{\beta}}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
p^0 - p^3
& -p^1 + i p^2
\\
-p^1 - i p^2 & p^0 + p^3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which for lightlike $p$ is a rank-one matrix, so can be expressed as an outer product of two spinors,
\begin{align}
|p\rangle^{\alpha}
 &=
 \frac{t}{\sqrt{p^0 - p^3}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p^0 - p^3
  \\
  -p^1 - i p^2
 \end{pmatrix}
\\
 [ p |^{\dot{\beta}}
 &=
 \frac{t^{-1}}{\sqrt{p^0 - p^3}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p^0 - p^3 & -p^1 + i p^2
 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
for any choice of $t$.  Then from the Dirac equation(?) we impose
$$
\left(|p\rangle^{\alpha}\right)^\ast
=
[ p |^{\dot{\alpha}},
$$
which imposes $t \in \mathbf{R}$.

The (Wigner) little group is the subgroup of Poincaré (?) transformations that fixes $p$ (the stabiliser of $p$?), which can be seen most easily if we boost into the momentum-aligned frame
$$
p^\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
{E} & {0} & {0} &{E}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Any rotation around the new $z$-axis, or any translation in the $xy$-plane, will leave $p^\mu$ invariant.

We can use spherical coordinates for $\mathbf{p}$ to parametrise a massless momentum vector as
$$
p^\mu = E \begin{pmatrix}
{1} & {\sin \theta \cos \phi} & {\sin \theta \sin \phi} &{\cos \theta}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
p^{\alpha \dot{\beta}}
=
2 E
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}
& - e^{-i\phi} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
\\
-e^{i\phi} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
&
\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which can be factorised as
\begin{align}
|p\rangle^{\alpha}
 &=
t
\sqrt{2E}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \sin \frac{\theta}{2}
  \\
  -e^{i\phi} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{pmatrix}
\\
 [ p |^{\dot{\beta}}
 &=
 {t^{-1}}{\sqrt{2E}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \sin \frac{\theta}{2}
 &
-e^{-i\phi} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}
 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
again for any choice of $t$. (this factorisation is equivalent to the above up to a redefinition of $t$ to incorporate a factor of $\mathrm{sgn} \left[ \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \right]$ arising from the square root)

Clearly this coincides with the momentum-aligned frame for $\theta = 0$, and there  is then a symmetry corresponding to the (now redundant) choice of $\phi$.  Is this redundancy essentially the little group?

For $\theta = 0$ we then have
\begin{align}
|p\rangle^{\alpha}
 &=
-e^{i\phi}
t
\sqrt{2E}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0
  \\
  1
 \end{pmatrix}
\\
 [ p |^{\dot{\beta}}
 &=
-e^{-i\phi}
 {t^{-1}}{\sqrt{2E}}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0
 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

So in this case $t$ and the exponential factor could be combined into a single factor, if we wanted to.  The $t$ factor alone is often (e.g. in Elvang and Huang) described as the 'effect of the little group' on the angle and square spinors.  Is this conflation with $e^{i\phi}$ the reason for this?  Why does it hold in any other frame than this one (if it does)?

Finally if we move to complex momenta, we can use the same parametrisation with complex $E, \theta, \phi$ and everything should carry through, with
$$
e^{i\phi}
=
e^{- \Im [\phi]} \left( \cos \Re [\phi] + i \sin \Re [\phi] \right)
.
$$
What is the little-group for complex kinematics isomorphic to and how is this manifest here?

Comment: Possibly [useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli–Lubanski_pseudovector#Little_group). This is the mainstream picture of textbooks.

Comment: You should be able from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Parabolic) to write down the three generators of E(2) comprising the little group commuting with your north pole case *p* matrix.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your comments. I think I understand the status of the little group in the usual real-momentum notation.  I guess to phrase my question a little differently, I'm interested both in how the 'textbook' picture changes when moving to complex momenta, and the explicit homomorphism I assume must exist for both real and complex momenta that allows us to identify some transformation of spinor helicity variables as the action of the little group upon them, for each little group element.